# How do I use raw input inside a function

Tags: python

I have scoured the forum trying to find a good way to make a function that takes raw input and uses it.

```
print "Roll for Agility"

def Rolling(a, b, value):

    in1 = raw_input()

    if in1 == 'roll':

        irand = randrange(a, b)

    elif in1 == 'Roll':

        irand = randrange(a, b)

    else: 

        print "Please Type <roll> in order to roll the dice."

        Rolling ()

    print "Your %d is %d" % (value, irand)

Rolling(1, 10, Agility)
```

It's supposed to take the numbers for the rolling range, and the number in the roll is inserted into a value (Agility in this case).

The code doesn't work because there's a problem with the raw input and the arguments put inside "Rolling function". I want the function not only to take raw input but also process it. I don't want to make raw input before the function and later add it manually into the function by putting the raw input into a string or int.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the error:     print "Your %d is %d" % (value, irand)
NameError: name 'value' is not defined

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. Fix those first please.

Comment: Are you talking about the indent issues? because it's like that only in the page here, not in the original code...

Comment: @YossiGershon: Fix the indentation here so we can tell what the original code is. Prefixing every line of code with an extra four spaces tells Stack Overflow to format it as a code block; right now, your indentation is clearly wrong (the second line of the function is at a lower indent than the first, but not as low as the `def` line, which is a `SyntaxError`; it's wholly unclear where the `print` is intended to be, etc. You also need to say what you mean by "doesn't work"; does it not output, does it raise an exception, does it produce incorrect output, etc.

Comment: `value` and `irand` are local variable and they exist only inside `Rolling` function - so you can't use them in `% (value, irand)` which is outside of `Rolling`

Comment: @furas: So how do I make a function that takes raw input and processes it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sorry, I have confused things and thought that `raw_input` was the function that `eval`s stuff. Left Python 2.x a long time ago. I have deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @YossiGershon you have to change indentions - like in AbhishekKedia answer.

Comment: I am trying to fix it. Can't press tab inside the writing box..

Comment: @furas: fixed indent issues. The last line doesn't want to be part of the code it seems.

Comment: @furas Why do people keep downvoting my post? I fixed the issues with it.

Comment: You still have problem with indentions - you need 4 spaces before last line. You code need: you indention + 4 spaces to correctly format on SO. Most people select code in editor, use tab key to add 4 spaces to all lines and then they copy-paste to SO. But maybe you get downvotes because your problem is too trivial and you shouldn't have this problem, or you made too many mistakes in question. Downvoting may meens that your problem is not usefull for others. Nobody can learn anything from your problem.

Comment: Just tried editing this using code and using 4 spaces and this happened...

Comment: @furas GOT IT! finally i managed to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has some typos. Error message `NameError: name 'value' is not defined` is generated because that statement has been mistakenly put outside the `Rolling` function body where `value` is not defined.

Corrected code should look like:

```
#Rolling for Agility
from random import randrange
print "Roll for Agility"
def Rolling(a, b, value):
    in1 = raw_input()
    if in1 == 'roll' or in1 == 'Roll':
        irand = randrange(a, b)
        print "Your %s is %d" % (value, irand) 
    else: 
        print "Please Type <roll> in order to roll the dice."
        Rolling(a,b,value) # using recursion to call again incase of erroneous input 


Rolling(1, 10, "Agility")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why would you once use s and once d?

Comment: Also, why can't I use reccursion by calling back my function so that if something that isn't Roll or roll makes the function be called again?

Comment: s=string, d=decimal/integer, f=float, etc. (btw: https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: @YossiGershon i) `s` is for formatting as string since string `"Agility"` is passed as `value` in `Rolling` ii) you definitely can use recursion to call `Rolling` function if incorrect value is typed in `raw_input`. Just ensure that `Rolling` is called with correct parameters because that was not correctly done in the question.

Comment: @AbhishekKedia Thank you very much. I added inside the else the following: Rolling(1, 10, "Agility") The program works but it gives me this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'irand' referenced before assignment.

Comment: @YossiGershon are you still getting that error? I tried reproducing it, but I am not getting the error. Can run the code https://gist.github.com/coderkd10/def9b9610c1a5155ee08e2dc21605273 and see if that still generates the error? or else can you post your code somewhere so that I can try running it on my system ?